# Smooth animation of three shapes in SciLab

Tags: animation, scilab

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38846393/6565614) provides a nice way to make smooth animations in SciLab. I now have to write a simulation of a body attached to two strings (and therefore its movement regarding some additional forces).

The code in the link works well to render movement of a single point and, unfortunately, I didn't manage to make an animation of a point + two lines using this method. If someone is curious, I tried this code to do it:

```
frametime=(tk-t0)/Nt//defining the waitnig time

plot(Y(1,1),Y(2,1),"o")//plotting the point
plot([0;Y(1,1)],[0;Y(2,1)],style=1)
plot([D;Y(1,1)],[0;Y(2,1)],style=1)//plotting the two initial lines
h1_compound = gce();
h_point=h1_compound.children
h_point.mark_size = 20;
h_point.mark_background = 2;
h_line1=h_compound.children
h_line2=h_compound.children
//h_axes = gca();
//h_axes.data_bounds = [0,-1;10,1];  
realtimeinit(frametime);
for i=1:Nt//my vectors have Nt points
  realtime(i);//wait "frametime" seconds before drawing the new position
  h_point.data=[Y(1,i),Y(2,i)];
  h_line1.data=[[0;Y(1,i)],[0;Y(2,i)]]
  h_line2.data=[[D;Y(1,i)],[0;Y(2,i)]]
end
```

The question is: is there any way to make an animation of three shapes without making axes blink (as it is with the window refreshment) or other wierd stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't reproduce your exact problem. But you may try to add `drawlater();` before, and `drawnow();` after your data modification to see if it does help with blinking or not.

Or you may get much better looking result by saving your plots in every round with `xs2gif` and assemble the animation with another gifmaker progam (there are free online sites to do this, however with some limitations). If you need to present your result, you should do this step anyway.